# textBox ontextChanged not firing when user adds text

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, textbox

I am creating a textBox within a repeater like this ( so there are many textboxes created inside a loop and added to the repeater control)

.aspx.cs

```
 TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
 textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
```

and I have a function like this for changing the textBox background color to white if that textbox has some text(it is yellow on creation of the form)

```
protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

but the function doesn't seem to be hit at all. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `YourTextBox.AutoPostBack = true;`?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question (sorry) but just a suggestion. You might be better off doing this with jquery and css rather than posting back to the server every time the user changes the text of the textbox.

Comment: I am almost glad it doesn't work for the sake of your users. :) Please  investigate how to do this with javascript!

Comment: I couldn't help it.. I made an example of doing it with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/pp4aA/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to save the round trip to the server and do it with javascript. When you create your control in the code behind add the **onchange** client event attribute and handle it:

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", 
       "this.style.backgroundColor = (this.value != '')?'#fff':'yellow';");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. This is the final code I used


textBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","javascript:changebackgroundcolor()");

Answer (score 0):

### Sample java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function runScript(evt, ID) {
        var ctl = document.getElementById(ID.id);
        if (ctl.value == '') {
            ctl.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00';
        }
        else
            ctl.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

---

### Sample Repeater Control HTML

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    textBox
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ed" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" onkeyUp="return runScript(event, this)" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help. This is the final code I used
.aspx.cs.

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress","javascript:changebackgroundcolor()");
```

.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changebackgroundcolor() {
            var element;
            for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
                element = document.forms[0].elements[i];

                switch (element.type) {
                    case 'textarea':
                        if (element.value.length > 0) {
                            element.style.borderwidth = "thin";
                            element.style.bordercolor = "White";
                            element.style.borderstyle = "solid";
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```